# Please review my solution on series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to see if the following series is convergent:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

I want to apply the limit test on the absolute value of the general term. We have:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}} = 1$$

Hence the original series is divergent. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes correct. More precisely you used two facts:

- the contrapositive of:  the series $\sum\limits_n a_n$ is convergent implies $a_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$
- the sequence $(a_n)$ tends to $0$ if and only if $\lvert a_n\rvert\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$